# implode with array

Tags: php

I have array in following format. I want to convert it into another format like below.

```
Array
(
 [b2] => 2
 [b3] => 8
 [b4] => 2
 [b5] => 4
)
```

Is it possible key is converted into PHP variables and its value automatically assigned to variables?Is it possible?
 `$b = 2;
  $b3 = 8;
  $b4 = 2
  $b5 = 4`
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

looks like you want [extract()](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function. You pass in the array you want to extract into the current scope, and that's it. Mind though that you should be very careful when you use this function; for safety, pass `EXTR_SKIP` in as the second argument to prevent overwriting existing variables, after all you wouldn't want the likes of `$_SESSION` or `$_SERVER` throttled by an array with malicious data...